# Adding a variable into a sql statement in Java

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to write a sql statement in java that uses a string variable in the where clause. I have tries multiple ways to do this but it keep telling me that I am not using the proper syntax. Can someone please tell me the right way to do this? The variable in this query is par_id.

> String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Tennis1294966077108.container_tbl WHERE parent_id =+"'par_id'"+ORDER BY creation_time asc";

Answer (score 11):

Use a PreparedStatement

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Tennis1294966077108.container_tbl WHERE parent_id = ? ORDER BY creation_time asc");
ps.setObject(1, par_id);
```

Comment: Hey Suresh,Im still getting a null pointer exception with that.

Comment: the line of this prepared statement

Comment: make sure you have created the connection

Comment: Ok so I got it figured out. This line does work. The problem was where I had each query closing. I have multiple queries in the application so the close statement ended up in the wrong place...noob mistake...Thank you very much for all the help! =)

Answer (score 1):

```
String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Tennis1294966077108.container_tbl WHERE parent_id='"+par_id+"'
ORDER BY creation_time asc";
```

Comment: Dont use string concatenation when passing data to a SQL statement. This is vulnerable for SQL injections.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for informing!

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM Tennis1294966077108.container_tbl " +
    "WHERE parent_id = ? ORDER BY creation_time asc");
ps.setInt(1, par_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM Tennis1294966077108.container_tbl WHERE parent_id = '" 
+ par_id 
+ "' ORDER BY creation_time asc";
```